# How to close a winform with powershell?

Tags: winforms, powershell

I have created a winform:

```powershell
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

function more {
$MoreTools                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$MoreTools.ClientSize             = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(903,473)
$MoreTools.text                   = "$title002"
$MoreTools.TopMost                = $false
$MoreTools.icon                   = "ressources\pictures\ico.ico"
$MoreTools.StartPosition         = 'CenterScreen'

$ButtonB                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$ButtonB.text                    = "$button007"
$ButtonB.width                   = 128
$ButtonB.height                  = 25
$ButtonB.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(387,350)
$ButtonB.Font                    = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Segoe UI',10)

$MoreTools.controls.AddRange(@($ButtonB))

$ButtonB.Add_Enter({
    $MoreTools.Close
})

[void]$MoreTools.ShowDialog()
}

more
exit
```

When I use exit or $MoreTools.Close it doesn't want to close.
So, how to close the form or where is the error?

Thanks

JJB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`add_Click()` method](https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2015/08/29/an-explanation-of-the-net-add_eventname-remove_eventname-methods/) rather than `Add_Enter()` on a button; moreover, `.Close` does not mean [`.Close()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close?view=net-5.0):

```
$ButtonB.Add_Click({
    $MoreTools.Close();
    $MoreTools.Dispose(); # facultative
})
```